# Possible to get value where exception occurred?

Tags: python, exception, try-except

Let say I have a for loop like this

```
data = [1, 2, 3, '4', 5]
for d in data:
    print(d * 0)
```

Output

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Then if I use `Try:` `except` blocks

```
data = [1, 2, 3, '4', 5]
try:
  for d in data:
    print(d * 0)
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Output

```
1
2
3
```

I wonder, is it possible to get the ***skipped value***
In this case `'4'`

Or in other words, is it possible to get the value that caused the exception?

My question is not related to just this piece of code but Python overall.

Comment: That question is more specific for exception with string right? I'm wondering like python overall if you get me.

Comment: That output is not what the program actually outputs... This program won't even cause an Exception, since `'4' * 0` is perfectly legal. So what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is easy, you have the value that failed and you catch that, simply use that value.

```py
for d in data:
   try:
      print(d+1)
   except TypeError:
      print('error caused by', d)
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but like in other situations. For example when using Dataframe. And a specific row is causing the exception. Is it possible to handle something like that?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but you could also print the row in the dataframe.

Comment: Okey, forget about Dataframe. Is it almost always possible to get the value that caused the exception, no matter what situation?

Comment: For a TypeError, yes. You will definitely be able to get the value that caused the error.